# Javascript error in simple Aurelia ASP.Net 5.0 RC1 Setup

Tags: javascript, asp.net, typescript, aurelia

I am attempting to setup a very basic Aurelia project in ASP.Net 5.0 RC1. I am getting the following JavaScript error after doing a basic initial setup. I am using TypeScript.

```
Unhandled promise rejection Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading  http://localhost:5392/core-js.js
    Error loading http://localhost:5392/core-js.js as "core-js" from http://localhost:5392/jspm_packages/npm/aurelia-loader@1.0.0-beta.1/aurelia-loader.js
    at o (http://localhost:5392/jspm_packages/system.js:4:12694)
    at XMLHttpRequest.s.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:5392/jspm_packages/system.js:4:13219)
    (anonymous function) @ es6.promise.js:138
```

The setup I did is as follows.

1. Create Empty ASP.Net 5.0 template.
2. Install `Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles` from nuget and set up `app.UseFileServer`.
3. From `git bash` run `jspm init` with the following settings.

   `Package.json file does not exist, create it? [yes]:
   Would you like jspm to prefix the jspm package.json properties under jspm? [yes]:
   Enter server baseURL (public folder path) [./]:./wwwroot
   Enter jspm packages folder [wwwroot\jspm_packages]:
   Enter config file path [wwwroot\config.js]:
   Configuration file wwwroot\config.js doesn't exist, create it? [yes]:
   Enter client baseURL (public folder URL) [/]:
   Do you wish to use a transpiler? [yes]:
   Which ES6 transpiler would you like to use, Babel, TypeScript or Traceur? [babel]:typescript`
4. From `git bash` run `jspm install aurelia-framework` and `jspm install aurelia-bootstrapper`.
5. Add the `index.html`, `app.html`, and `app.ts` file from the aurelia docs.
6. Fire up IIS Express, load page, get error.

Is there a step I am missing in this setup?

Comment: does `jspm install core-js` fix it?

Comment: Does not do anything other than install babel as a transpiler. core-js is already installed via the jspm install of Aurelia.

Comment: Seems like it's a known issue. Took me a while to find it. https://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/241

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is a [known issue](http://github.com/aurelia/framework/issues/241). The fix is somewhat simple. If you add a `core-js` mapping at the top of the map section in `config.js`, it fixes it.

For example,

```
map: {
    "core-js": "npm:core-js@1.2.6",
    // other mappings
}
```